# 1 coefficient not defined because the design matrix is rank deficient

Tags: r

I am trying to let a linear regression including a variable *agesq*, which is the square of my variable age. However, when I run it I get this whole big mess with a warning that 1 coefficient  not defined because the design matrix is rank deficient. So now I don't know how to make it look normal? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```r
    Call:
    lm_robust(formula = bwght ~ educ + age + agesq1, data = dataset, 
        se_type = "HC1")

    Standard error type:  HC1 

    Coefficients: (1 not defined because the design matrix is rank deficient)
                Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)  CI Lower CI Upper
    (Intercept) 4430.915    174.238  25.43020 1.727e-90  4088.536  4773.29
    educ          24.519     14.146   1.73330 8.369e-02    -3.278    52.32
    age          -56.062      5.004 -11.20439 5.347e-26   -65.894   -46.23
    agesq1256   -616.703    138.783  -4.44366 1.103e-05  -889.411  -343.99
    agesq1289   -490.818    241.907  -2.02896 4.302e-02  -966.165   -15.47
    agesq1324   -353.403    146.284  -2.41586 1.608e-02  -640.852   -65.95
    agesq1361   -423.800    253.727  -1.67030 9.552e-02  -922.373    74.77
    agesq1400   -520.329    270.949  -1.92040 5.541e-02 -1052.743    12.09
    agesq1441   -103.543    137.794  -0.75144 4.528e-01  -374.309   167.22
    agesq1484   -384.309    145.781  -2.63620 8.660e-03  -670.769   -97.85
    agesq1529   -255.879    141.196  -1.81222 7.059e-02  -533.329    21.57
    agesq1576     30.512    119.088   0.25622 7.979e-01  -203.495   264.52
    agesq1625      6.602    140.228   0.04708 9.625e-01  -268.946   282.15
    agesq1676     61.922     99.986   0.61930 5.360e-01  -134.552   258.39
    agesq1729    270.231     97.304   2.77718 5.701e-03    79.028   461.43
    agesq1784    283.877    121.984   2.32716 2.038e-02    44.178   523.58
    agesq1841    140.055    146.646   0.95506 3.400e-01  -148.104   428.21
    agesq1900    414.970    132.890   3.12266 1.902e-03   153.841   676.10
    agesq1961    288.429    151.363   1.90555 5.732e-02    -8.999   585.86
    agesq11024   271.397    109.406   2.48065 1.346e-02    56.415   486.38
    agesq11089   660.253    138.565   4.76494 2.519e-06   387.973   932.53
    agesq11156   830.817    121.925   6.81417 2.902e-11   591.234  1070.40
    agesq11225   528.925    108.404   4.87920 1.459e-06   315.911   741.94
    agesq11296  1049.191    162.288   6.46497 2.532e-10   730.294  1368.09
    agesq11369   620.048    242.961   2.55204 1.102e-02   142.628  1097.47
    agesq11444   913.331    106.979   8.53746 1.895e-16   703.117  1123.55
    agesq11521  1007.073    236.204   4.26358 2.431e-05   542.932  1471.21
    agesq11600  1067.886    154.501   6.91184 1.558e-11   764.291  1371.48
    agesq11936        NA         NA        NA        NA        NA       NA
                 DF
    (Intercept) 472
    educ        472
    age         472
    agesq1256   472
    agesq1289   472
    agesq1324   472
    agesq1361   472
    agesq1400   472
    agesq1441   472
    agesq1484   472
    agesq1529   472
    agesq1576   472
    agesq1625   472
    agesq1676   472
    agesq1729   472
    agesq1784   472
    agesq1841   472
    agesq1900   472
    agesq1961   472
    agesq11024  472
    agesq11089  472
    agesq11156  472
    agesq11225  472
    agesq11296  472
    agesq11369  472
    agesq11444  472
    agesq11521  472
    agesq11600  472
    agesq11936   NA
```

Comment: You accidentally made `agesq1` into a factor.  Can you show us how you processed the data to derive that variable?

Comment: You might be able to fix it via `dataset$agesq1 <- as.numeric(as.character(dataset$agesq1))` but it would be better to go upstream and figure out where/why it happened (and fix it there)